# For loop seems faster than NumPy/SciPy 3D interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, numba

I feel confused about NumPy/SciPy interpolation methods. I implemented 3D linear interpolation with `LinearNDInterpolator` and I found it very slow. Then I wrote a brute-force triple for loop approach in pure Python, and surprisingly it give me 1000x speedup. I gave a shot for the Numba package as well, and it did not turn out to be any faster.

By any source that I found on the internet, Python loops should be superslow compared to NumPy/SciPy and Numba. But this is not what I see.

I post the whole source code that I run. I get these times on my machine:

```
Numpy ready:  3.94499993324  s,  result[0]=  0.480961746817
Python for loop...
Python ready:  0.0299999713898  s,  result[0]=  0.480961746817
Numba for loop...
Numba  0  ready:  0.223000049591  s,  result[0]=  0.480961746817
Numba for loop...
Numba  1  ready:  0.0360000133514  s,  result[0]=  0.480961746817
```

I use Anaconda Python 2.7. What am I missing here?

```
import numpy
import scipy.interpolate
import time
from numba import jit


# x: a (40,) numpy array of ordered ints
# y: a (30,) numpy array of ordered ints
# z: a (10,) numpy array of ordered ints
# values: a (10,30,40) numpy array of floats
# targetxs: a (NP,) numpy array of random floats
# targetys: a (NP,) numpy array of random floats
# targetzs: a (NP,) numpy array of random floats


NP=1000

def numpyInterp(x,y,z,values,targetxs,targetys,targetzs):

    start=time.time()
    zz, yy, xx = numpy.broadcast_arrays(z,y[:,numpy.newaxis],x[:,numpy.newaxis,numpy.newaxis])
    grid=numpy.reshape(numpy.array([zz,yy,xx]).swapaxes(1,3),(3,-1)).T
    values3D=numpy.reshape(values,-1)

    print 'Reshape matrix: ',time.time()-start
    start=time.time()
    f=scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator(grid,values3D)
    print 'Interpolation: ',time.time()-start
    #start=time.time()
    #result1=[f(targetzs[i],targetys[i],targetxs[i]) for i in range(len(targetzs))]
    #print 'Evaluation (list comprehension): ',time.time()-start
    # I found that map is slightly (not much) faster on my machine than list comprehension
    start=time.time()    
    result=numpy.squeeze(map(f,targetzs,targetys,targetxs))
    print 'Evaluation (map): ',time.time()-start    
    return result


def pythonInterp(x,y,z,values,targetxs,targetys,targetzs):

    nx=len(x)
    ny=len(y)
    nz=len(z)

    ntarget=targetxs.shape[0]

    result=numpy.zeros((ntarget,))

    for targ in range(ntarget):
        westix=len(x)-2
        eastix=len(x)-1
        for ix in range(1,nx):
            if targetxs[targ] <= x[ix]:
                westix=ix-1
                eastix=ix
                break

        southiy=len(y)-2
        northiy=len(y)-1     
        for iy in range(1,ny):
            if targetys[targ] <= y[iy]:
                southiy=iy-1
                northiy=iy
                break

        upiz=len(z)-1
        downiz=len(z)-2
        for iz in range(1,nz):
            if targetzs[targ] <= z[iz]:
                downiz=iz-1
                upiz=iz
                break

        xratio=(targetxs[targ]-x[westix])/(x[eastix]-x[westix])
        yratio=(targetys[targ]-y[southiy])/(y[northiy]-y[southiy])

        lowerresult=values[downiz,southiy,westix]+(values[downiz,southiy,eastix]-values[downiz,southiy,westix])*xratio+(values[downiz,northiy,westix]-values[downiz,southiy,westix])*yratio+(values[downiz,northiy,eastix]-values[downiz,northiy,westix]-values[downiz,southiy,eastix]+values[downiz,southiy,westix])*xratio*yratio
        upperresult=values[upiz,southiy,westix]+(values[upiz,southiy,eastix]-values[upiz,southiy,westix])*xratio+(values[upiz,northiy,westix]-values[upiz,southiy,westix])*yratio+(values[upiz,northiy,eastix]-values[upiz,northiy,westix]-values[upiz,southiy,eastix]+values[upiz,southiy,westix])*xratio*yratio

        result[targ]=lowerresult+(upperresult-lowerresult)*(targetzs[targ]-z[downiz])/(z[upiz]-z[downiz])

    return result

@jit
def numbaInterp(x,y,z,values,targetxs,targetys,targetzs):

    nx=len(x)
    ny=len(y)
    nz=len(z)

    ntarget=targetxs.shape[0]

    result=numpy.zeros((ntarget,))

    for targ in range(ntarget):
        westix=len(x)-2
        eastix=len(x)-1
        for ix in range(1,nx):
            if targetxs[targ] <= x[ix]:
                westix=ix-1
                eastix=ix
                break

        southiy=len(y)-2
        northiy=len(y)-1     
        for iy in range(1,ny):
            if targetys[targ] <= y[iy]:
                southiy=iy-1
                northiy=iy
                break

        upiz=len(z)-1
        downiz=len(z)-2
        for iz in range(1,nz):
            if targetzs[targ] <= z[iz]:
                downiz=iz-1
                upiz=iz
                break

        xratio=(targetxs[targ]-x[westix])/(x[eastix]-x[westix])
        yratio=(targetys[targ]-y[southiy])/(y[northiy]-y[southiy])

        lowerresult=values[downiz,southiy,westix]+(values[downiz,southiy,eastix]-values[downiz,southiy,westix])*xratio+(values[downiz,northiy,westix]-values[downiz,southiy,westix])*yratio+(values[downiz,northiy,eastix]-values[downiz,northiy,westix]-values[downiz,southiy,eastix]+values[downiz,southiy,westix])*xratio*yratio
        upperresult=values[upiz,southiy,westix]+(values[upiz,southiy,eastix]-values[upiz,southiy,westix])*xratio+(values[upiz,northiy,westix]-values[upiz,southiy,westix])*yratio+(values[upiz,northiy,eastix]-values[upiz,northiy,westix]-values[upiz,southiy,eastix]+values[upiz,southiy,westix])*xratio*yratio

        result[targ]=lowerresult+(upperresult-lowerresult)*(targetzs[targ]-z[downiz])/(z[upiz]-z[downiz])

    return result






# Declare input data grid coordinates
z=numpy.arange(10000,100001,10000)      # 10
y=numpy.arange(30,60) # 30
x=numpy.arange(0,40)  # 40


# Initialize values (pointwise sin)
zz, yy, xx = numpy.broadcast_arrays(z,y[:,numpy.newaxis],x[:,numpy.newaxis,numpy.newaxis])
grid=numpy.array([zz,yy,xx]).swapaxes(1,3)[0,:,:,:]
values=numpy.sin(grid)

# Initialize points for interpolation
targetxs=numpy.random.random((NP,))*40
targetys=numpy.random.random((NP,))*30+30
targetzs=numpy.random.random((NP,))*90000+10000


# Running functions
start=time.time()
print 'Numpy...'
a=numpyInterp(x,y,z,values,targetxs,targetys,targetzs)
print 'Numpy ready: ',time.time()-start,' s,  result[0]= ',a[0]


start=time.time()
print 'Python for loop...'
a=pythonInterp(x,y,z,values,targetxs,targetys,targetzs)
print 'Python ready: ',time.time()-start,' s,  result[0]= ',a[0]

for i in range(5):
    start=time.time()
    print 'Numba for loop...'
    a=numbaInterp(x,y,z,values,targetxs,targetys,targetzs)
    print 'Numba ',i,' ready: ',time.time()-start,' s,  result[0]= ',a[0]
```

Comment: If your values are on a regular grid, then you shouldn't be using an interpolator that's meant for irregular data. (It will be much slower, as you've noticed.)  What you want is actually `scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates`. `LinearNDInterpolator` is meant for "scattered" points. Most of the time is spent calculating distances.  If the data is already on a regular grid, there are much, much more efficient approaches (similar to your loop). `map_coordinates` uses these approaches.

Comment: Or a `RegularGridInterpolator` (only available in scipy 0.14) http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator

Comment: numba is not giving you any performance improvement because you have to create the array outside the jitted function and use `nopython=True`.

Answer (score 1):

The two functions loop very differently internally, `numpyInterp` runs over every element of the broadcasted array, while your `pythonInterp` assumes the data is on a grid and only runs over each dimension. So really what is happening is that one loop is O(N^3), while the other is O(3N), which explains the speedup you're seeing.

You could use interpolation methods from scipy.ndimage, as your data is sitting on a regular grid, which should be even faster.